# Linux display color settings

Tags: linux, drivers, arch-linux, nvidia-graphics-card, colors

**Original Question**
(This was originally why I posted. But I figured it out, and am putting question and solution here.)
The first portion of my problem was that my display contrast and color depth was way off. I had been using these [Test Images](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/)  (Contrast, Black Level, and White Saturation pages), and it looked as if all the colors were squished into RGB 20-235 and everything outside of that range is assumed to be the extreme value (0 or 255).
The problem turned out to be that my *monitor* was set to Limited RGB 16-235 the whole time. Switching it to Full RGB fixed the color contrast.
In conclustion: make sure that both your monitor and graphics settings are set to full RGB.

**New Question**
The second portion of my question is about how to set ICC color correction on Linux. I already have an ICC profile for my monitor.
What is a good way to install it?

**System Info**
I am running Arch Linux x64 with an Nvidia GTX970 graphics card connecting to my monitor via HDMI.
I have nvidia 375.10-1 proprietary graphics driver installed, along with nvidia-libgl and the nvidia-settings tool.